# How to map objects in two arrays into one?

Tags: javascript

I have the following two arrays with the same length:

```
Arr1 = [{"id": "1","name": "test"},{"id": "1","name": "test"}]
Arr2 = [{"code": "1","section": "alpha"},{"code": "1","section": "gama"}]
```

I would like to map Arr1 and Arr2 by index and create a new array like the following:

```
arr3 = [
  {"id": "1","name": "test", "code": "1","section": "alpha"},
  {"id": "1","name": "test", "code": "1","section": "gama"}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work for you? Please read the following helpful article with several links inside to see the types of questions that really do well here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
let arr1 = [{"id": "1","name": "test"},{"id": "1","name": "test"}]
let arr2 = [{"code": "1","section": "alpha"},{"code": "1","section": "gama"}];

let arr3 = arr1.map((obj, idx) => Object.assign({}, obj, arr2[idx]))
console.log(arr3)
```

Or the  [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let arr1 = [{ 'id': '1', 'name': 'test' }, { 'id': '1', 'name': 'test' }]
let arr2 = [{ 'code': '1', 'section': 'alpha' }, { 'code': '1', 'section': 'gama' }]

let arr3 = arr1.map((obj, idx) => ({ ...obj, ...arr2[idx] }))

console.log(arr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment

```js
let arr1 = [{"id": "1","name": "test"},{"id": "1","name": "test"}]
let arr2 = [{"code": "1","section": "alpha"},{"code": "1","section": "gama"}];
console.log(arr1.map((obj,index)=>obj={...obj,...arr2[index]}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce),Try this

```js
const arr1 =  [ { "id": "1", "name": "test" }, { "id": "1", "name": "test" } ]
const arr2 = [ { "code": "1", "section": "alpha" }, { "code": "1", "section": "gama" } ]

console.log(arr1.reduce((acc, ele, i)=>(acc.push({...arr2[i], ...ele}), acc),[]))
```